# apache2 server not starting

Tags: apache2

I am new to apache2 (server management in general). When I am running the command `apachectl start` from: `/apache2/bin`, I am getting the error:

```
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

When I do `netstat -an | grep ":80"`, I can see that there is no process/webservice running on port 80.

```
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

This is very weird and I cannot find a solution as to how to start the apache2 server. Please Help!

Comment: Are you root when you start the server?

Comment: What do you get if you run `netstat -alt | grep "http"`? Some servers will simply refer to port 80 as http.

Answer (score 0):

try with **sudo apachectl start** ?

Comment: did that, still not working.. the location of the server just changed and on doing ifconfig I do get the new/changed IP address...

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

There can be multiple reasons. First of them is an application is using Port 80.

Second is that you might have Web Deployment Agent Service on or World Wide Web Publishing Service. So stop these by going to control panel and typing administrative tools and click component services then click services (local) in side bar then scroll to the "W" section till you see the Web Deployment Agent Service and the World Wide Web Publishing service and click stop!

That should free Port 80.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo service apache2 start
```